# Rails/unicode issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

I have a bit of my Ruby/Rails (Ruby 2.0.0p195, Rails 3.2.13) project that works as a proxy; that is, you pass it a URL, it goes out and fetches the page, and presents it to you.  This generally works as expected, but it seems to munge certain characters (such as è).

A simplified version of the controller is this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def geoproxy
    require 'net/http'
    require 'timeout'

    rawurl = CGI::unescape(params[:url])

    fixedurl = rawurl.gsub('\\', '%5C')   # Escape backslashes... why oh why???!?
    r = nil;

    status = 200
    content_type = ''

    begin
      Timeout::timeout(15) {        # Time, in seconds

        if request.get? then
          res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(fixedurl))

          status = res.code    # If there was an  error, pass that code back to our caller
          @page = res.body.encode('UTF-8')
          content_type = res['content-type']    
        end
      }

    rescue Timeout::Error
      @page = "TIMEOUT"
      status = 504    # 504 Gateway Timeout  We're the gateway, we timed out.  Seems logical.
    end

    render :layout => false, :status => status, :content_type => content_type
  end
end
```

The corresponding view is quite simple:

```
<%= raw @page %>
```

When I use this proxy to fetch XML containing an è (for example), I get the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in HomeController#geoproxy
"\xE8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

This error occurs at the following line:

```
@page = res.body.encode('UTF-8')
```

If I remove the .encode(), the error is resolved, but my XML contains a placeholder instead of the è.

How can I get my project to display the XML properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check if the following code works for you? I was able to fix similar problem of mine with it.

```
@page = res.body.force_encoding('Windows-1254').encode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Much to my utter shock and amazement, your suggestion worked.  An alternative that also worked, that I like better for some reason, is this:  @page = res.body.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8').  Do you have any idea _why_ this works?

Comment: Different character sets may represent same characters. In this case, since both character sets are able to convert the character 'è' to '00E8' or '\xE8' it's normal that both encodings produce the same result. There might be other character sets that can do this as well. You just be sure that the type of encoding you use will be able to handle kind of characters you would get from 'res.body'.

Comment: This much I understand, but not why doing a force_encoding to one character set, then re-encoding in UTF would work.  I know that Ruby defaults to UTF-8, so I'm not sure why I had to set the encoding at all, nor why simply encoding in UTF-8 did not work.